# Interpreting a given space

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology

I am doing some homology theory for which I need to compute the singular homology groups of the following space:

$X=\mathbb S^1$x $\mathbb D^2$ \ {$(1,0)$}

$1)$ My first question is how to interpret this space, does it mean like taking $(1,0)$ from $\mathbb S^1$ and also taking $(0,0)$ from $\mathbb D^2$ or like taking the point $(1,0)$ from both of these two spaces?

$2)$ In any case, when computing homology groups, how can I use the fact that I know that $\mathbb D^2$ is contractible, i.e.

am I allowed to use homotopy invariance firstly on this product $\mathbb S^1$x $\mathbb D^2$ and then remove the point $(1,0)$ which would certainly lead me to an easy computation or am I not? 
And why so?

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: I would guess this is a very bad notation. To remove the pair $(1,0)$ from $\mathbb S^1\times\mathbb D^2$ you must have $1\in\mathbb S^1$ and $0\in\mathbb D^2$. Both is not very clear. But I would assume that the $1$ is meant to be $e^{0\cdot 2\pi i}\overset\sim=(1,0)$ in $\mathbb S^1$ and $0$ is the origin $(0,0)$ in $\mathbb D^2$. So actually they should have written something like this: $\mathbb S^1\times\mathbb D^2\setminus \{e^{0\cdot 2\pi i},(0,0)\}$. Or completely different, they want to remove $(1,0)$ from $\mathbb D^2$ before the product, but who knows.

Comment: You can use the Kunneth formula for cross product, maybe?

Comment: To be honest, I am not familiar with the Kunneth formula...

Comment: @Eurydice That is unfortunate, for I learnt it only recently. You have thought of using Mayer-Vietoris, I presume. Which are the open sets you have in mind?

Comment: this space should be homotopy equivalent to a torus with a disk glued onto a meridian if it's the first space M. Winter mentioned.

Comment: @астонвіллаолофмэллбэрг I have thought about MV, you are right, but I have trouble with taking the proper open sets. At first I thought of taking for one of them, say $U$, a ball around this removing point large enough to completely collaps with the torus boundary (since now I undestand that the space can be interpreted as torus filled inside but with one point removed) and for the other, say $V$ I was thinking of taking the complement of this ball but together with the boundary sphere of $V$.

Comment: $U$ can be def. retracted to $\mathbb S^1$ and the intersection is $\mathbb S^1$ already but what about $V$? At first, I thought it is contractible to a point, but now I get that this doesn't have to hold necessary.